# sfp and sfp28 compatibility

Tags: freebsd, 10gbethernet, sfp, broadcom

I have gotten a server which has "Broadcom 57454 10/25GbE SFP28 4-port OCP Ethernet Adapter" When I connect it to a switch port which is sfp the link status on the server is reported as active and it even sends packets for the DHCPDiscover but the packets never reach the server, the switch is unifi. The OS which I have tried is ubuntu18/Ubuntu22.10, right now I am trying freebsd 13, I load driver as a module at boot time I used loader.conf, I made following entry.

```
 if_bnxt_load="YES"
```

Is sfp28 backward compatible with sfp OR am I missing the driver for "Broadcom 57454 10/25GbE SFP28 4-port OCP Ethernet Adapter" which is causing the problem ?

Comment: You'll have to find the manual for the *actual* card you have. The chip in theory supports this, but for instance Lenovo's cards only lists 10 and 25GbE.

Comment: ok thanks, the server is ThinkSystem SR650 V2.

Comment: BTW, do we need to install the driver for the card ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/lp1198-thinksystem-broadcom-57454-25gbe-ethernet-adapters#supported-transceivers-and-cables that NIC is only compatible with a single SFP for 1000BASE-T, feature code A5DL.

When mixing 1G/10G/25G transceivers on a single link

1. optical transceivers have to share the same wavelength (e.g. 1000BASE-SX and 10GBASE-SR)
2. the higher-speed transceiver has to be backward compatible with the lower speed - for twisted-pair transceivers that is (more) common but not a given for optical ones

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing sfp28 is compatible with sfp+ but it doesn't work with sfp.